# H3 and Anchor Tag bottom aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with Bootstrap 3.0 and would like to accomplish something along these lines

**Favorites**               [Add](http://www.nooop.com)

Where favorites  is pulled left and wrapped in an H3 and the add is pulled right and wrapped in an anchor.   They are bottom aligned and on the same  line.

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
<div class="vertical-gutter-xs row container">
   <div class="row">
      <div clas="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid red"><h3>Favorites</h3></div>
      <div clas="col-md-6" style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid red"><a>add</a></di>
   </div>
   <hr />
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. I don't think it's semantically logical to have favourites in a heading tag. 2. Put "Favorites" and the anchor in a different span. They'll align automatically. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/wVkEe/1/ Also, you don't need the `hr`. You can simply put a border-bottom on `.row´.

Comment: Thanks that is definitely an option, but since I am dealing with a legacy site, I was hoping to use the styling they already have defined  including the H3 tag.  I haven't put a ton of thought into CSS design, you may very well be right about the logic of having favorites in the heading, honestly I was just trying to prevent redefining the styling of most of the H3 tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
<div class="vertical-gutter-xs row container">
  <div class="row">
    <div clas="col-md-6" style="float:left; width:50%;"><h3>Favorites</h3></div>
    <div clas="col-md-6" style="float:right; width:50%; text-align: right"><a>add</a></div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: I went with this type of solution...  Had to fudge the styling on the h3 but it works

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `pull-right` link inside the `H3`..

```
<div class="col-md-6"><h3>Favorites <a href="#" class="pull-right">add</a></h3></div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/87773

Comment: I think this is better than my solution above.